# Error "unresolved reference : activity_splash "

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I just created new empty activity in Android studio.

Splash Activity Class:

```
    package com.example.layoutpractice

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle

    class Splash : AppCompatActivity() {

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)
        }
    }
```

Splash Activity XML file:

```
    //activity_splash.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you can see, 
I made no changes to the code.
But I still get an error in Android Studio.
[image: Splash.kt]

I even deleted and recreated the .xml file as recommended by the Android editor, but it didn't change.

Comment: show your imports

Comment: where are you importing R file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that is there any import like

```
import android.R
```

if its there remove it and reimport

Comment: Its issue in import , Do Post your imports too

Comment: My imports: import "import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle" , "import android.os.Bundle"

Comment: I added import android.R in import, but still occurs error

Comment: clean and rebuild your project, and reimport by removing it, also can try to invalidate catch, Don't import above namespace manually

Comment: After rebooting Android Studio and creating the activity again, the error went away. thanks

Comment: Some times this error is also caused by duplicate id in the same layout or by the duplicate layout file

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate Caches and restart Android Studio. `File` -> `Invalidate Caches / Restart...`